# I cannot use component from one module into another module component

Tags: angular

I have two modules, MapModule and LeftListModule. Inside MapModule I have MapComponent, and inside LeftListModule, LeftListContainerComponent.

What I want is to use LeftListContainerComponent into MapComponent, as follows

```
<p>map works!</p>
<app-left-list-container></app-left-list-container>
```

To do this, I have configured LeftListModule on this way

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LeftListContainerComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports:[LeftListContainerComponent]
})
export class LeftListModule { }
```

And MapModule like this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MapComponent, LeftListContainerComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class MapModule { }
```

I have researched on the internet, I have found several results, but I don´t understand where the problem is.

I am having this message:

ERROR in map/map.component.html:2:1 - error NG8001: 'app-left-list-container' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-left-list-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-left-list-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

```
2 <app-left-list-container></app-left-list-container>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  map/map.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './map.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component MapComponent.
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that in your *LeftListModule* you do export the component but in the *MapModule* you do not import the module from which the component is exported. You need to add *LeftListModule* in the imports of your second module

OR

Relocate the shared component in a Shared module and add this shared module in both imports

Comment: I have the shame problem using shared module

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `LeftListModule` into your `MapModule`.

Comment: @NgModule({
  declarations: [MapComponent, LeftListContainerComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, LeftListModule
  ]
})
export class MapModule { }I am doing this, but I still have the problem

Comment: You shouldn't be declaring `LeftListContainerComponent` in `MapModule`.